# Why does python serial read the last thing I wrote instead of the response from my serial device

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, pyserial, gpio

I have a numato 128 GPIO board that is functioning correctly when I type commands into the terminal but my python program is not getting the same results. When I write the command to read from the IO board and wait 1 second and then read what's in the buffer I end up reading back the command I just sent instead of the response from the device. If I read through everything in the buffer, it will eventually return the response. This is on a Raspberry Pi. Here is my code.

```py
import serial
import time

class UsbSerial:
    def __init__(self, serial_conf):
        self.ser = serial.Serial(serial_conf['port'], serial_conf['baud'])

    def readGPIO(self, pin):
        self.ser.write("gpio read " + ("000" + str(pin))[-3:] + "r")
        time.sleep(1)
        return self.ser.readline()

ser_conf = {"port": "/dev/ttyACM0", "baud": 19200}
serGPIO = UsbSerial(ser_conf)
print serGPIO.readGPIO(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not pretty, but this is the modified readGPIO submodule that seems to do the job.  I would still appreciate input on how to make it nicer.

```
    def readGPIO(self, pin):
        self.ser.flush()
        self.ser.write("gpio read " + ("000" + str(pin))[-3:] + "r")
        time.sleep(.1)
        x=self.ser.readline()
        x=self.ser.read(1)
        x=self.ser.read(1)
        y=self.ser.read(1)
        #time.sleep(.1)
        self.ser.flush()
        return x
```

Comment: It means you papered over the real issue and who knows what can be wrong in the future.